# What will cause all WarehouseControlWebService methods to return "Value cannot be null.&#13;&#10;Parameter name: securityNamespace"

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2017

BLUF:
Pointing a browser at this UI on the SSRS:
/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
And selecting any method and clicking 'Invoke' causes the web UI to throw a 500 and the response body is:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: securityNamespace

Background: I've just upgraded on-prem TFS to 2018 update 1, which was a pretty easy process.  Rather than trying to backup/recover the SSRS/SSAS databases to the new data tier, I am trying to just create a new TFS warehouse because last time that was far easier.  I've set up SSAS and SSRS, configured SSRS with a new database using a domain service account, set up Reporting in the TFS console (everything is green), used it to create the TFS Warehouse, Configured the collection's reports folder (also green), uploaded the reports from the template to the SSRS web interface and verified that the data sources test successfully with the service account.  Updated the reports to use that data source and observed that the Reports, when viewed in the web UI complain about missing fields.  Looking at the TFS_Warehouse database, only the dimPerson table contains records (actual users/computers and groups that are relevant) (after a full 24 hours).  Looked in the Event Viewer, SSRS logs and TFS logs and can't find clues as to why the Warehouse is not populating.  I've re-accomplished the SSRS, SSAS and TFS configuration a few times--same results.  Right now the domain account that I'm using in this environment and the service account have every possible permission that I can give to them regarding TFS,SSRS/SSAS, the databases, etc.  Has anyone seen this securityNamespace error before when attempting to invoke the web service methods for SSRS?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried this solution: Try to type the TRUE into includeOnlineHostOnly field, then press Invoke button.   in this similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65ecc274-d528-4336-b20c-1d7cb94fd876/tfs-2012-warehousecontrolwebservice-get-processing-status-invoke-fails-error-500?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: Yes--I've come across that one.  I've added TRUE to that parameter with the same 500 result mentioning the securityNamespace parameter being null.  Even if I try to invoke 'GetSettings' which has no parameters, I get that error.  Thanks.

Comment: So I was able to get the Warehouse to build. In TFS Admin console, clicked Edit under Reporting/turned off Reporting.  Restarted TFS Server, in Edit dialog/turned Reporting on with a new Warehouse database and new Analysis instance, started the jobs and this time everything populated.  All I did differently was Stop using Reporting Services and restart before trying again.  One report works now, but one that uses the OLAP source does not (cube not processed yet?).  Still getting the securityNamespace error trying to get status.

Comment: The data cube processed and the other report works now.  So my crisis is over.  However--still can not invoke any WarehouseControlService methods.